# ruby on rails - using string for link_to and formatting it for hyperlink name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a db that has a column src_url, that contains full urls to web resources.
Currently I use

```
<%= link_to "source", @article.src_url %>
```

to display it.

What I want to do is to display first 2 or 3 domain levels instead of "Source" (so for example "www.example.com" or "example.org").

I'm fairly new to ruby on rails, so having to figure out about everything on the go, this one I was stuck on for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`URI`](http://apidock.com/ruby/URI) module:

```
uri = URI(@article.src_url)
uri.host
#=> "example.com"
```

This module is already included in Rails, so you should not include it manually.

Comment: Not sure how to use this. Do I add this to one of .html.erb files in view or somewhere else?

Comment: Currently my project is fairly simple: it consists of sqlite db, 1 controller and a bunch of view files. It essentially begun with tutorial on guides.rubyonrails.org and from there I kept adding and changing stuff. I'm still only figuring out what goes where, so I'm a little lost every now and then.

Comment: It worked, thanks! Used <%= link_to URI(@article.src_url).host, @article.src_url %>